# Far vs far away

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes we store things on top of the cabinets. (Over it). I was putting a box on top of the cabinet, but maybe I used a lot of force:

> The box went really **far/far away** that I couldn't get at it.
>
> I threw the box really **far/far away**.

What sounds natural "far" or "far away"? What's more likely to be used?If neither of them sounds natural, what will sound natural?

Comment: (1) *I threw the ball really far.* (2) *I threw the ball really far **toward** the hole.* (3) *I threw the ball really far **away** from the hole.*

Answer (score 1):

In most cases they should be pretty interchangeable grammatically, but do mean slightly different things. "Far" is a description of the distance travelled, when the end point doesn't really matter. "Far away" refers more directly to the final location.

If I am explaining how hard I threw a ball I might say *"I threw the ball really far"*

If, on the other hand, I am describing where the ball landed I would instead say *"I threw the ball really far away"*

Comment: So what will sound natural in my context?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to emphasize that the box landed out of reach, so "far away" would be appropriate. But if you need to also stress that it was a result of how hard you threw it, maybe try something like "I threw the box too hard and it landed so far away I couldn't reach it."